Is there a way to crop an image to specific shape?
I have a photo that I want to put inside a language assignment and part of the foreground (chicken wire) is used as a frame, and I want to crop the photo to just outside the frame. Is this possible in Preview or Photos, and if not, what would be the best software to quickly do this?
Here is the image in question:


Your question seems unclear to me (or maybe I'm just thick?) Are you saying that you want to crop the picture in the hexagonal shape of the chicken wire fencing? If so, I've not seen a crop tool that could do that... you might want to try some of these that claim to be able to do it.

@Seamus ...Hmm maybe... I think Wix can do it? I don't have it, but I do have Adobe Photoshop, and that of all things should cut it. Thanks!

i spent so long trying to blur my face out...

Solved it, Photoshop can do it.
Create a path and you can.. I think it's Image > Vector Mask > From Path?

Persistence pays off  :)
